# Extracting JSON objects in Athena / Presto for dynamic keys

Tags: sql, json, amazon-athena, presto, unnest

I have two `string` formatted columns in my table. One of the columns has json objects in it. The keys in the JSON objects are not fixed - so the problem is I cant use standard json extract functions. Here is how the table looks

| timestamp | upstream_tables |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-02-02T17:34:55.946Z | {"ETL_table_1":true,"ETL_table_2":true} |
| 2023-02-02T13:30:11.882Z | {"ETL_table_3":true} |
| 2023-02-02T20:12:22.116Z | {"ETL_table_4":true,"ETL_table_5":true,"ETL_table_6":false} |

I want to flatten this table to something like below

| timestamp | upstream_tablename | was_completed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-02T17:34:55.946Z | ETL_table_1 | TRUE |
| 2023-02-02T17:34:55.946Z | ETL_table_2 | TRUE |
| 2023-02-02T13:30:11.882Z | ETL_table_3 | TRUE |
| 2023-02-02T20:12:22.116Z | ETL_table_4 | TRUE |
| 2023-02-02T20:12:22.116Z | ETL_table_5 | TRUE |
| 2023-02-02T20:12:22.116Z | ETL_table_6 | FALSE |

Can anyone please help? Have spent a lot of time using map_values and map_keys but couldnt get it right.

The only closest thing I could come up with was this

```
select
   timestamp,
    t.*
FROM mytable
   CROSS JOIN UNNEST(map_entries(CAST(json_extract(upstream_tables, '$') AS MAP(VARCHAR, VARCHAR)))) AS t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@martin-traverso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2958752/martin-traverso)'s answer can be used with Athena engine v. 3 which is based on Trino, for both v.2 and v.3 the main trick of casting to `map` you have discovered, I would switch from using `json_extract` to `json_parse` (to transform from string to json), skip `map_entries` (Presto/Trino can unnest maps to key-value pairs, optionally use `MAP(VARCHAR, JSON)` as target type) and specify column names for unnest result, Presto/Trino can unnest maps to key-value pairs:

```sql
WITH data(ts, value) AS (
    VALUES
        (from_iso8601_timestamp('2023-02-02T17:34:55.946Z'), VARCHAR '{"ETL_table_1":true,"ETL_table_2":true}'),
        (from_iso8601_timestamp('2023-02-02T13:30:11.882Z'), VARCHAR '{"ETL_table_3":true}'),
        (from_iso8601_timestamp('2023-02-02T20:12:22.116Z'), VARCHAR '{"ETL_table_4":true,"ETL_table_5":true,"ETL_table_6":false}')

)
select
   ts,
    t.*
FROM data
   CROSS JOIN UNNEST(CAST(json_parse(value) AS MAP(VARCHAR, JSON))) AS t(upstream_tablename, was_completed);
```

| ts | upstream_tablename | was_completed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-02 17:34:55.946 UTC | ETL_table_1 | true |
| 2023-02-02 17:34:55.946 UTC | ETL_table_2 | true |
| 2023-02-02 13:30:11.882 UTC | ETL_table_3 | true |
| 2023-02-02 20:12:22.116 UTC | ETL_table_4 | true |
| 2023-02-02 20:12:22.116 UTC | ETL_table_5 | true |
| 2023-02-02 20:12:22.116 UTC | ETL_table_6 | false |

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a combination of [`UNNEST`](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html?t#unnest) and [`json_query`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html?#json-query).

First, use `json_query` to convert all the field-value pairs to a normalized form
with the shape `{"name": "xxx", value: yyy}`. Then, convert these to an array of
rows and unnest them into individual rows.

```
WITH data(ts, value) AS (
    VALUES
        (from_iso8601_timestamp('2023-02-02T17:34:55.946Z'), VARCHAR '{"ETL_table_1":true,"ETL_table_2":true}'),
        (from_iso8601_timestamp('2023-02-02T13:30:11.882Z'), VARCHAR '{"ETL_table_3":true}'),
        (from_iso8601_timestamp('2023-02-02T20:12:22.116Z'), VARCHAR '{"ETL_table_4":true,"ETL_table_5":true,"ETL_table_6":false}')

)
SELECT ts, t.name, t.value
FROM data, UNNEST(CAST(json_parse(json_query(value, 'strict $.keyvalue()' WITH ARRAY WRAPPER)) AS array(row(name varchar, value boolean)))) t(name, value)
```

**Update (2024-01-12)**

In recent versions of Trino, you can use `json_table()` to extract the values directly, without the need to parse the json data manually or cast it:

```
WITH data(ts, value) AS (
    VALUES
        (from_iso8601_timestamp('2023-02-02T17:34:55.946Z'), VARCHAR '{"ETL_table_1":true,"ETL_table_2":true}'),
        (from_iso8601_timestamp('2023-02-02T13:30:11.882Z'), VARCHAR '{"ETL_table_3":true}'),
        (from_iso8601_timestamp('2023-02-02T20:12:22.116Z'), VARCHAR '{"ETL_table_4":true,"ETL_table_5":true,"ETL_table_6":false}')

)
SELECT data.ts, t.name, t.value
FROM data,
   json_table(
       data.value,
       'strict $.keyvalue()'
       COLUMNS (
           name VARCHAR PATH 'strict $.name',
           value BOOLEAN PATH 'strict $.value'
       )
   ) AS t
```